What tool can I use to remove this cabinet shelf?
I need to remove this wood shelf from a kitchen cabinet.  However, it seems to be glued in place along the edges.  What tool can I use to remove it as cleanly/flush as possible without damaging the rest of the cabinet?  Sawzall?  Oscillating tool?  A toe kick saw?  Something else?


That was probably put into a dado type cut in each side of the cabinet.

Note that the shelf may be accounting for part of the strength of the cabinet.

The shelf was built as part of the cabinet. It will be impossible to remove without resulting in obvious scars.  If you state your reason for wanting / needing the shelf to be removed, you may get viable options here.

Do you care about removing the shelf nondestructively?

I am trying to retrofit a bottom mount pull-out garbage bin into this space.  It's definitely big enough but the shelf has to go.

How wide is the pullout and how wide is the shelf?
